# YouTube V3 Data API on iOS returning unplayable content

Tags: ios, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm experimenting with the YouTube API in my iOS app and using the below get request generated from [here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?videoEmbeddable=true&videoType=any&videoDefinition=any&order=relevance&part=snippet&videoDimension=any&q=taylor%20swift&videoCaption=closedCaption&videoLicense=creativeCommon&videoSyndicated=true&type=video&videoDuration=any&videoCategoryId=10&maxResults=10&_h=13&) with my actual API key.

GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?videoEmbeddable=true&videoType=any&videoDefinition=any&order=relevance&part=snippet&videoDimension=any&q=taylor+swift&videoCaption=closedCaption&videoLicense=any&videoSyndicated=true&type=video&videoDuration=any&videoCategoryId=10&maxResults=10&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

As you can see, I've specified that I am querying for "Taylor Swift" and only want music videos (category ID 10) that are able to be played outside YouTube. I also have a YTPlayerView that I implemented to play inline as discussed [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper#adding_ytplayerview). However, in my search results, I am consistently getting videos that say "This video contains content from *. It is restricted from playback on certain sites."

Why are these results showing up even when I explicitly state I only want playable content? Am I missing something or did I not implement the player correctly?

Comment: You can try setting videoLicense=youtube as one of the parameter.

Comment: @Dhruv just tried that and it's still sending back unplayable content